# How to create usable variables in functions or loops with use:strict on

Tags: perl, loops, variables, scope, global

I have a loop that parses some XML. In that loop, there are several more loops that if certain values are present, I create an array and put values in it like this:

```
for (@{ $product->{$basename} }) {

    # there are two values for PACKAGE. create a unique list for each value
    $package = $_->{PACKAGE};

    if ($package eq "RETAIL") {
        ...values read from xml...
        push (@myListRetail, [$one, $two, $three];
    }

    if ($package eq "ADVISOR") {
        ...values read from xml...
        push (@myListAdvisor, [$one, $two, $three];
    }
```

After the main XML parse loops closes, I then test for the existence of those arrays, and put them into a new array:

```
# add this array to the package name array
if (@myListRetail) {
    push @packageNames, \@myListRetail;
}

# add this array to the package name array
if (@myListAdvisor) {
    push @packageNames, \@myListAdvisor;
}
```

This is all good, simple, and works.

But, I don't have use:strict on. When I turn it on, I get the "explicit package" warning because I'm creating the arrays without "my".

I don't have them predeclared as "my @myListRetail" etc.,outside the loop, because I need to test for their existence. If I declare them with "my" inside the loop, they are scoped and I can't get them.

I know I should have strict on, but when I do, the script breaks because of the "my" error.

How can I define and create a variable in a loop that I can use outside the loop (or function or any other scope) and still use it elsewhere in a script?

Comment: Why not test whether they're empty instead? Or put the arrays in a hash under their respective key (`RETAIL` and `ADVISOR`), that way you can remove some duplicated code as well.

Comment: I did try to see if they were empty but I must have had some syntax wrong. I'll look at that again.

Comment: `if ( @myListRetail > 0 )`

Comment: Or just `if ( @myListRetail )` - as he already has.

Comment: Aside from the declaration of the two arrays, it looks like you want `my @package_names = grep @$_, \(@my_list_retail, @my_list_advisor)` which does the same as your two `if` statements. Note also that, while you're brushing up your Perl to `use strict` etc. it would be nice if you followed the common Perl practice of reserving capital letters for *global* identifiers such as `Package::Names`. Local identifiers generally use just lower-case alphanumerics and underscore, although you will find a sizeable minority of non-compliant code in CPAN if you look.

Answer (score 3):

> After the main XML parse loops closes, I then test for the existence
>   of those arrays, and put them into a new array:
>
> ```
> # add this array to the package name array
> if (@myListRetail) {
>     push @packageNames, \@myListRetail;
> }
> ```

The check `if (@myListRetail)` doesn't 'test for the existance` of @myListRetail as you seem to think. It checks for the number of elements in @myListRetail. And if the array contains no elements it returns zero - which Perl evaluates as false.

So it seems to me that this is already doing exactly what you want. All you need to do is to declare these arrays outside of your main loop and everyone (including `strict`) will be happy.

Comment: Precisely. It seems that another reason to always `use strict` is that it helps people to understand basic Perl functionality. I believe that, had the OP been using best practices from the start he wouldn't have misconceived the idea of testing for the *existence* of a variable. It's possible but awkward to test for the existence of package variables, and to my knowledge doing the same for the more usual lexical variables is impossible without employing the `PadWalker` module. It's certainly not a recommended technique!

Answer (score -3):

test if there is at least one element :

```
 if ($myListRetail[0]) {
    push @packageNames, \@myListRetail;
}
```

Comment: And if the first element is `0`?

Comment: Or size array scalar @arr : `if (scalar @myListRetail > 1) ...`

Comment: *`> 0` (and you can leave out `scalar`)

Comment: Or, simply, `if (@myRetailList)`.